# Log4Net not rolling on MaxFileSize

Tags: c#, logging, configuration, log4net, rollingfileappender

Somehow my log4net not rolling to a new file when the old log file exceeds the MaxFileSize and also stop writing log information to the already exceeded one. But when I restart the server, it did rename the old one to ServerLog.txt.1 and create a new file ServerLog.txt and write to that file.

Here is my log4net.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<log4net debug="true">
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs\ServerLog.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Can someone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that log4net cannot create/rename the backup file caused by file permission problems? Where is the log file located?

Comment: It is located in the same directory with the web application Website/Logs/ServerLog.txt I set the NETWORK SERVICE account to Read/Write/Modify already?

Comment: It don't see a problem.  It is behaving like rollingStyle = Once, make sure you didn't override that in your source code.

Comment: No I didn't, in the source code all I did was loading the log4net.xml config file, that's all :( It stop logging when the file size get to the max value and don't create new file?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your problem may arise from using the log from IIS. Since there is the possibility of having different app domains accessing the log file from within IIS, there may be issues with an app domain not being able to roll the file because the log file is also opened in another app domain.

You would need a locking model setup with your appender to prevent the app domains from colliding when accessing the file.

You should be able to do something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<log4net debug="true">
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs\ServerLog.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
    </layout>
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MutexLock" />
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the appendToFile value to false. See http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.RollingStyle.html

Answer (score 1):

Change "rollingStyle" to "Composite" in Config worked for me.

```
<log4net debug="true">
  ....  
  <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
  ....
</log4net>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing the 'staticLogFileName'.  We use pretty much the same config settings as you; but we donot specify staticLogFileName property. (This is a shot-in-the-dark; because it should be okay to set the staticLogFileName to true)